# Maximal soluble subgroups in a parabolic subgroup of finite classical simple group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, simple-groups

I'm new to algebaric groups, so please accept my apology in advance if I post crazy questions.

Let $G$ be a classical simple group over a finite field $GF(q)$ and $P$ a parabolic subgroup of $G$ stabilizing an isotropic subspace. Is the Borel subgroup of $G$ maximal soluble in $P$ and is there any maximal soluble subgroup in $P$ besides the Borel subgroup? Here by maximal soluble I mean a maximal one among  soluble subgroups of $P$.

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: You are allowed to post crazy questions, as long as someone can understand you enough to answer. =)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Hope someone understanding my question kindly answer it:-)

Comment: If you ask the [same question here and on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114333/maximal-soluble-subgroups-in-a-parabolic-subgroup-of-finite-classical-simple-grou), please give a link to the other page to avoid duplicated work by people not checking both pages!

Comment: @jug Oh, sorry, I should give a link. Thanks for reminding me!